# Using paramiko when a unix server is using VShell

Tags: python, paramiko

**Use case**

On a unix server , when login manually ,opens a command shell of its own to run the command.

[image: Vshell prompt]

I am trying to automate this by using paramiko , however , somehow i am  not able to execute the command on command shell using paramiko

**What i have done ?**

I created a simple script which is able to make connection, but its not executing command on Vshell as the ouput is always coming empty.

```
import paramiko
import sys

ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=sys.argv[1],port=sys.argv[2],username=sys.argv[3],password=sys.argv[4])
command="show hwid"
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command(command)
out=stdout.read()
print out
err=stderr.read()
print err
ssh_client.close()
```

The same script runs perfectly fine , when its used on server where **vshell** is not being used

Anyhelp or suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1):

```
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command(command)
```

Regarding this line of code, I suspect that the SSH server is not properly configured to allow commands to be executed in this way (this is the equivalent of `ssh myserver show hwid`, rather than typing it into the terminal after login).

You might want to imitate the behaviour of typing the command in after logging into the server, and for that I think this is appropriate:

```
shell = ssh_client.invoke_shell()
stdin, stdout, stderr = shell.exec_command(command)
```

Comment: its raising exeception paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHExceptionn: Channel closed

Comment: Although  this did not exactly solved my problem, but i used invoke_shell method as suggested by you to solve my problem, i will update my answer